# Trouble understanding VADER sentiment analyser NLTK

Tags: nltk, sentiment-analysis, vader

I have some trouble understanding output of vader based on case of input. Here is an example. I want to know the reason for this kind of behaviour as IMO, if a sentence is in caps, it should add emphasis value and give an even more weighted result. Instead, I think it thinks this is kind of sarcastic or something.

```
In [17]: sentiment_analyse(str.lower("I WILL NEVER RECOMMEND HIM TO ANYONE......."))
compound: -0.2755, 
neg: 0.297, 
neu: 0.703, 
pos: 0.0, 
negative

In [18]: sentiment_analyse("I WILL NEVER RECOMMEND HIM TO ANYONE.......")
compound: 0.3612, 
neg: 0.0, 
neu: 0.667, 
pos: 0.333, 
positive
```

Comment: Guessing here: The caps just prevent it from matching the words to the training data, so it just takes a wild guess. And most reviews are positive...

Comment: Should not be the case. eg. "DISAPPOINTED" and "disappointed" gives same result.

Comment: I looked into the code and saw some ##Constants## to increase and decrease sentiment polarity depends on ALLCAPs to emphasize chosen words. I think this is the reason why you get a different answer for ALL CAPS, but to find why exactly these values was derived I advise to debug step-by-step code. Good luck.